# Disabling clickable footnotes

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

Is there a way to disable clickable footnotemark, but still keep the rest of the hyperref functionality? That is, references etc. should be clickable but footnotes should not be.

My document has a couple of places which has both references and footnotes adjacent to each other. The box around them creates clutter. So I would like to on disable the boxes for footnotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hyperref has an option for this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}\label{xx}

\ref{xx}\footnote{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]